# PS Plus Collection - what is it and how do I access it?

Tags: playstation-plus, ps5

I’ve signed up for PS Plus Essential which includes the Playstion Plus Collection:

[image]

According to Sony’s own website, this includes a list of games:

[image]

However, taking the first game on that list as an example - Bloodborne - the PlayStation app tells me I need to upgrade my subscription to access it:

[image]

Have I misunderstood? Is the website misleading? If not, how do I access these games?

Comment: Do you own a PS5? This collection is only available for PSPlus (Essential and above) & PS5. It works for me (also in the App) and I have both.

Comment: @d4zed yes, I only have a PS5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to get the game from the store, it will think you are just buying it.
With the subscription you own the "PS Plus Collection", you just have to download the games from there.

The *PS Plus Collection* can be viewed when hovering over the PS Store icon on the PS5 main bar:

[image]

Or accessed from the Game Library:

1. Go to your Game Library
2. Select between all your purchased and installed titles
3. Select the *PS Plus Collection* tab and claim your titles in order to download them to your PS5 console

[image]

Comment: “ If you try to get the game from the store, it will think you are just buying it.” If that’s the case, why is it giving me the option to upgrade my subscription?

Comment: Maybe because those games are also in the deluxe catalogue at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Temporary answer while I wait to verify it (I’m waiting for a young person to submit control of the console): it’s implied [here](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/support/subscriptions/subscribe-ps-plus-download-monthly-games/) that you have to download them directly from the console. I’m not sure why the app wouldn’t align with that.

Comment: Because it's stated that's an exclusive feature for PS5, so there will be no reason to let people redeem that from the app. You need to prove you own it, I guess.

Comment: @pinckerman it does seem to let me download the games directly on the console without any extra charge.